# MS Teams bot events

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I have a notification-only bot, and I would like to send a welcome message to users only when the bot is added to a personal conversation.

I listen to 'conversationUpdate' events as stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bots-notifications#team-member-or-bot-addition), though I keep receiving the same event multiple times one after the other for the same user, all events identical (except the event ID and timestamp).
I respond to the event with HTTP status 200 (I handle them via REST).

Does anyone have an idea why I would receive the same events multiple times and how to avoid it? Is it some kind of retry due to an unexpected response on my end?

It even says [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bots-notifications#bot-added-for-personal-context-only): "For personal scoped bots, your bot will only ever receive the conversationUpdate event a single time, even if the bot is removed and re-added."

Comment: Receiving the the same event multiple times mean is user is installing/Uninstalling the bot for many times? Could you please explain when the event is getting called in more detail?

Comment: can you answer the above-asked question?

Comment: For personal scope you will receive the conversation update event for the time, this is by design. Are you receiving the event for second time also? if yes, Could you please share the manifest?